# php ilegal string offset error

Tags: php, android

[image]

[image]

Why except courseID, courseTerm shows appropriately? I used json_encode.

```
echo json_encode(array("response"=>$response), JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

and used alertdialog to see my data

[image]

Comment: why it's value is 'r'??

Comment: Please include your code _directly in your question_.  Do not use images for code, copy/paste the actual code.  When you use images, we are unable to test/run your code (along with other reasons mentioned [HERE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1505169) ), making it infinitely harder for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Line 63 and 64 : "row" should be "$row" , no ?

Basically, you are trying to access to a variable `row["courseId"]` . But "row" is not a variable. It should be `$row["courseId"]` .